# error TS2440: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'Highcharts3d'

Tags: typescript, highcharts, angular-material, angular-cli

I am trying to run my application in VS code and I keep getting the error:

```
error TS2440: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'Highcharts3d'
```

please help to me to fix this error

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
    import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
    import * as Highcharts3d from "highcharts/highcharts-3d";
    
    declare var require: any
    
    let Highcharts3d:any = require("highcharts/highcharts-3d");
    let HighchartsExporting = require("highcharts/modules/exporting"); 

    Highcharts3d(Highcharts);
```

Comment: This is because you have a duplicate variable declaration rename the variable declaration - rename let Highcharts3d to something different.

Comment: Yeah, try the approach from the above comment. If this wouldn't help - please reproduce a basic demo showing the issue.

Comment: Thanks @RRR it worked , I just forget it, Thanks for correcting my mistake

Answer (score 10):

### **Problem**: You have a duplicate variable declaration:

- `import * as Highcharts3d from "highcharts/highcharts-3d";`
- `let Highcharts3d: any = require("highcharts/highcharts-3d");`

rename the variable declaration - rename let Highcharts3d to something different.

### **Solution:** Rename either

- `import * as different_name from "highcharts/highcharts-3d";`
- OR
- `let different_name: any = require("highcharts/highcharts-3d");`