Typescript namespaces for conflicting variable names
I have a component with the same name as a class that is being imported. Without changing the name of one of them, what is a solution to this issue?
Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'RangeFilter'.typescript(2440)

I have found a solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66148858/26809672:
import * as RangeFilterNamespace from './classes/RangeFilter';

Then use:
let a: RangeFilterNamespace.RangeFilter; 
But I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this in Typescript.
Has anyone encountered this kind of issue before and how do you implement your solution?
import { RangeFilter } from "./RangeFilter"; // <- error
import * as x from "./RangeFilter";

function RangeFilter() {
  let test: RangeFilter;
  let a: x.RangeFilter; // solution from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66148858/26809672
}

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dzf52p?file=%2Fsrc%2FRangeFilter.tsx%3A6%2C3-6%2C25

import { RangeFilter as RF } from "./RangeFilter";

Note that this is primarily a JS question.
